# RE internship possibilities

Tags: idc

I am currently studying computer science and I have to do a mandatory internship (6 months) soon. I am really enjoying re and I would love to get an internship in that area. My problem is that the number of re internship jobs I found on various job search engines is extremely limited to quite non existing.

Do you have any ideas where I could look for jobs instead? I am living in germany but I also wouldnt mind to move to a nearby country.

Thank you very much!

Comment: There are very few legitimate reasons for a normal company to do any sort of reverse engineering. Analyzing virus/malwares is probably the main one. So maybe you can try browsing the homepages of some companies that sell antivirus products/services to see if they provide such jobs, or even contact them directly.

Comment: @WhatsUp verifying the security of a product is also a legitimate or better legal reason at least in the EU or Germany. Otherwise you would have to trust everything a manufacturer says without a chance to verify it. Also verifying security of products e.g. software is much easier than reversing malware.

Comment: Please disregard what @WhatsUp said, there are a myriad of legitimate reasons for companies to do reverse engineering, like these ones: https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/6455/what-are-the-targets-of-professional-reverse-software-engineering/6458#6458

Comment: @joxeankoret Well, you can post an answer to this question if you are so confident about the information you gave.